# Infopath - expand dropdown list values

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have a combo box on my form, that reads values from a list. Is there an option to allow the users to fill their own values and add them the same time to the list? I would like to avoid directing the users to the list, add the new value and reopen the form. The users have of course the necessary rights on the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that InfoPath allows this. Filling their own values works on multiselect columns but I don't think that it works on lookup columns. Maybe you can try to add new items using web services with InfoPath. Also you can use WorkFlow to add new item to another list.